# php server settings for restrict post queries

Tags: apache-2.2, php, configuration

I have php script on hosting, which receive big data with ajax/post.

Just now, after some works on hosting, I see that script is broken.

I checked with curl:

file temp1:

```
user_avatar=&user_baner=&user_sig=....
```

237 chars total, and

```
curl -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -X POST --data @temp1 'http://host/mypage.php'
```

works perfect.

But with file temp2:

```
name=%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B1%%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%A4%%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%8A&user_payed=0000-00-00&...positions%5B5231%5D=on
```

total chars: 65563

```
curl -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -X POST --data @temp2 'http://host/mypage.php'
```

curl return nothing.

Looks like a problem with apache/php/php.ini or something like that.

I check .htaccess

```
php_value post_max_size 20M
```

Which other parameters I should check?

Is it possible that %BO encode kill php/apache?
Or total number of parameters (about 2800) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was php_value max_input_vars

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you may be hitting a limit imposed by the [suhosin patch](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/) for PHP - specifically the [suhosin.post.max_value_length](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.post.max_value_length) parameter.

Is there anything in the web server's error_log which could help?

Comment: Nothing interesting in error log, but in access log I see request, and length of response - 0

Comment: Sometimes suhosin logs to syslog.